# Opamp Supply Current vs Output Transition Frequency

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, frequency

I am dealing with an NC2200 op amp that should consume no more than 10uA. 
But the datasheet shows the following graph, which I haven't found something exactly like that to understand what does mean exactly:

[image]

Simply put, does that mean that supply current increases with the output frequency? So if I amplify a signal of 10kHz at 5V supply, I consume 20uA instead of 10?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an op-amp, it's a comparator and therefore one can now assume that the graph in your question is when the output pin is switching between rails (full range). This will charge up and discharge internal capacitors and, when you do this, it equates to an equivalent real current draw over and above the residual current consumption for all the internal bias circuits.

Many CMOS gates mention in their data sheets an equivalent capacitance and, that equivalent capacitance can be used to calculate the current consumption when operating at a significant switching frequency. The NCS2200 is no different in reality.

> *Simply put, does that mean that supply current increases with the
>   output frequency? So if I amplify a signal of 10kHz at 5V supply, I
>   consume 20uA instead of 10?*

Simply put no, you probably shouldn't be using this as a linear amplifier unless the "comparator" data sheet explicitly states that it can be used that way. If it can be used as a linear amplifier then no, the circuit won't necessarily consume 20 uA at 10 kHz unless you are forcing the amplifier into saturation on both rails or have a significantly high output peak-to-peak level.

Comment: So if I amplify a rail-to-rail signal at 10kHz? Does in that case consume around 20uA?

Comment: I modified the question accordingly :)

Comment: Why have you modified the question? Part of my answer justifies why the graph is what it is and therefore not related to what you'd find in a regular op-amp. To save me work, why don't you revert back to the previous question because then, my answer makes more sense. It's up to you; if you don't revert back I'll copy what you said in the original question and embed it into my answer so that folk will know why I answered that particular way. Just more work for me and that seems unfair. Generally you should not modify a question once it has attracted an answer because it just pisses folk off.

Comment: Regards your previous comment, what part of my answer that explains about this don't you understand?

Comment: Done, reverted back. sorry.

Comment: Cool, better now.

Comment: Essentially I got that my assumption was correct (except that apply only on out rail to rail signals), but I got confused in the last paragraph. One because you explicitly mentioned the fact that in linear mode won't consume that way (and ok), but after you say "unless you are forcing the amplifier into saturation on both rails or have a significantly high output peak-to-peak level". I don't know what you mean by saturation on both rails, or high p-to-p level in this case, because seemed to be the use case of a comparator.